# SQL query 1:N references

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

**What I'm looking at**

I want to know if it's possible to create a *SELECT* that shows in one row the follow informations from 2 tables:

*Pseudo-Code* :

```
SELECT
    Data_Car,
    Car_Holders_Data 
FROM Car, Holder_Data 
WHERE
    Car.License_PLate_PK = Holder_Data.License_Plate.FK
```

**My Tables**

```
CAR(License_Plate_PK, Frame, Car_Info)
Holder_Data(License_Plate_FK, Holder_Data)
```

**My result**

```
License_Plate |        Frame        |     Car_Info's     | Holder_Name
   AA001AA       VF7UA9HR8CJ615652        Car Things       Mario Rossi
   AA001AA       VF7UA9HR8CJ615652      Same Car Things    Luigi Verdi
```

**What i want to achieve**

```
License_Plate |       Frame        |     Car_Info's     | Holder_Name1   | Holder Name2
   AA001         VF7UA9HR8CJ615652       Car Things       Mario Rossi      Luigi Verdi
```

(I wrote car things just because I have something like 30 columns about car info. It's just to simplify, you can easily ignore that column)

I know that my query will return 2 or more rows if there are 2 or more Holders. Is there a way to return all holders in the same row?

I'm using MS SQL Management Studio 2008

Comment: Please tag your DBMS (version included)

Comment: done, i'm using ms SQL management studio 2008

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: What is the goal of having them in one row? Do you want the count of them, or them comma separated?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @kchason i need to export the query on excel. i'm not really good with excel managing so I'm looking if there's a way to do it after the export and not during or before by editing the xlsx sheet.

Comment: So if there are 15 holders, you want 15 new columns? Or you know it has a max of 2 (or N) possible holders?

Comment: Edit with a better explanation. @EzequielLópezPetrucci if there are N holders i want N columns

Comment: @jarlh sorry but my sql knwoledge is based on what i studied at school...

Comment: Your sample results show that you have two different car infos, why "Car Things" and not "Same Car Things?" Separately, depending what you're doing in Excel, you may want to have them in distinct rows for charting, etc...

Comment: @kchason as i said i need to have only 1 row for every car, indipendent of how many holoders it has! I wrote _car things_ only because i have something like 30 columns of car infos

Comment: Is that not relevant to the question? Do you have the logic for generating  the comments into their own columns? Why not duplicate that for the users?

Comment: @kchason car things is not relevant, sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: @kchason I don't know how many car with N holders will be so i cannot create a standard header for every car. I got something like 800 cars.
At the moment i have duplicate rows except for the holder's data every time I got a car with 2 or more holders

Comment: You're pivoting, and this is quite easy in Excel (but beyond the scope of this question) and rather difficult in older versions of SQL Server. I would export this as you have it, then do the pivot in Excel since you're already planning on housing the data there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168548/discussion-between-simo-and-kchason).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL doesn't allow an indeterminate or dynamically changing number of columns.  This means that you would need to decide in advance how many `holder` columns you want to have.

The following code, for example, pivots your `holder_data` table *(which you can then join on to your `car` table)*.  It assumes a maximum of three holders.

```
SELECT
  license_plate,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 1 THEN name    END)   AS holder_1_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 1 THEN address END)   AS holder_1_address,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 2 THEN name    END)   AS holder_2_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 2 THEN address END)   AS holder_2_address,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 3 THEN name    END)   AS holder_3_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN row_id = 3 THEN address END)   AS holder_3_address
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY license_plate ORDER BY some_date_field)  AS row_id
  FROM
    holder_data
)
  AS sorted_holder_data
```

If you wanted that to dynamically change based on the number of holders you would need to do it in several steps.
  1. run a query to find out the max number of holders
  2. run some code that writes SQL to repeat the `MAX(CASE)` sections multiple times
  3. run the sql written by your code using `sp_executesql`

That's a lot of laborious effort, right?  There must be a better way natively support by SQL?

You're right.  SQL is designed from the ground up to achieve its relational nature by using normalised data.  That is, to think about the structure of the data from a programming perspective, rather than a human friendly presentation perspective.

Conveniently, you already have your data in a normalised structure.  So, if you want the true SQL way of doing things, ***don't*** pivot your data.

But, what about presentation???

That's not what SQL is for.  SQL is a data storage and processing language.  It's not designed or intended to work on presentation.  You should keep the presentation layer of your design ***separate*** from your data layer.  Mixing the two causes all sorts of maintenance issues further down the line.  It's a false economy because the longer you try to stick with this de-normalised way of thinking the more difficulty you ***will*** experience with SQL.  Don't do it, keep you SQL Data structures normalised, that's what SQL is for.

Instead, this pivotting should be done in your presentation layer.  Be that Excel or SSRS or QlikView or Tableau or whatever.  They too know about normalised data and are actively gear up for transforming normalised data in to human presentable formats.

***EDIT:***

I just read that your wrote this in your comments:

> i'm not really good with excel managing so I'm looking if there's a way to do it after the export and not during or before by editing the xlsx sheet.

There's your problem right there.  Because you're not confident with Excel you want to use SQL to do it for you.  Unfortunately SQL is the wrong place, and Excel is the right place.  You need to learn how to do it in Excel.

Look in to Pivot Tables, Power Pivot, VBA *(Visual Basic for Applications)*, etc.  Excel has numerous ways of doing what you want, and I would strongly advise you to learn how to use the correct tool for the job, rather than bludgeoning the wrong tool in to doing a bad job for you.

Comment: At the end i was able to pivot it inside Excel. Thanks for the support!